# Mac iTunes requests update, but App store says no updates available

Tags: itunes, macos, mac-appstore, software-update

Recently I got a iPhone 5 with iOS 9.3 installed.  On connecting it to my computer iTunes said that I needed at least iTunes 12.2.2.  I had 12.0 at the time.  Mac Running Yosemite.

I clicked download, and App Store launched, and said I had no updates available.

Went through this loop several times.

Called Apple.

Spent an hour on the phone, while the very personable agent walked me through the direct link (support.apple.com/kb/dl1814) Clicking the download button there got me to another page.  Clicking download there got me a "Thanks you for downloading..." but the download didn't begin.

I repeated this step with chrome, firefox and safari.  No joy.

Booted into safe mode.  Didn't help.

Went to two other computers, my wife's where I don't have a login, and my laptop, which runs snow leopard.r  No joy from either of those.

We left the ticket unresolved.

Answer (score 1):

Since the apple advisor was able to perform the download at his end, but I was not able to at my end, my suspicion was that there was a problem with Apple's content distribution network.

This morning I tried again.  No joy.

On a hunch I tried logging in on a spare admin account.  No problem. connected to  the apple support site, and downloaded the update. Worked like a charm.

At this point it's not clear what happened, but with odd behaviour it does bring up one additional possibility to try:

Attempt the update as a different user.

Comment: If your answer solves your question, please [accept](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer.  This helps others who might have the same, or similar, problem as you did.

Comment: I would rather leave it unmarked as best answer, due to my not knowing why it worked.  This will encourage other answers.